# Pulling contents of div tags with beautifulsoup and creating a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
date = '2017-08-04'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MLB Daily Data.xlsx')

url_4 = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/'+date
resp_4 = requests.get(url_4)
soup_4 = BeautifulSoup(resp_4.text, "lxml")
lineups = soup_4.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'players'},limit=None)

row_lineup = 0
for lineup in lineups:
    lineup1 = lineup.prettify()
    lineup2 = lineup1.replace('>'&&'<',',')
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(eval(lineup2))
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Starting Lineups', startrow=row_lineups, startcol=0)   
    row_lineups = row_lineups + len(df.index) + 3
writer.save()
```

I am trying to get the starting lineups from the webpage, convert it them into a pandas data frame, and then save it to an excel file. I'm having an issue with turning it into a data frame. I replaced the brackets with commas because I figured that would turn it into csv format.

Comment: It was my best guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you moving in the right direction, where each line is a line up

```
data = [[x.text for x in y.findAll('a')] for y in lineups]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: This was perfect! i just changed the 'a' to 'div' so I could get the position and handedness as well. I'm new to python so stuff like [[x.text for x in y.findAll('a')] for y in lineups] I wouldn't think to do myself. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to Help! In case you did not know this is called list comprehension, and can be helpful for creating lists vs. typical loop with append.

Comment: It seems like a useful tool to have. Would it work with div tags of different classes? I had BeatifulSoup also scrape the "team-name" div tag with along with the lineups, which worked fine and output all the tags I need, but when I ran that same code to turn it into a list the lineups were imported fine but the team names were imported as blank spaces.

Comment: It would depend on the data you scraping, You have to find out the structure and then see how it would fit into the dataframe, i.e. what values are stored in the tag. If something is stored in another tag, and you want to add it as a new columns you could do something line `df['NewValues'] = [x for x in linups.findall('tag')]`

Comment: Its hard to explain in comments, but you just have to mess around until you can get the data formatted correctly